mysql only one event not running
mysql version 8.0.35
CREATE EVENT my_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2024-03-01 00:00:00.000'
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO update my_table set my_column=0

This event will not run after June 8th.
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.events

LAST_EXCUTED column is not updated after 2024-06-08 00:00:00
but other events work normally
What should I look for?

I checked INFORMATION_SCHEMA STATUS column is 'enabled'

I checked 'event_scheduler = ON'

I checked 'SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0' because of the 'without where clause update warning statement'.

I checked that there is no record of that event in mysql log



MySQL does not log event_scheduler unless there is an exception. So check the error log to find more.

Last_executed? What and where is that?

The inference is that last_executed is a timestamp and the update didn't cause any changes..

'last_executed' is the most recent time the event was executed as recorded in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.events
